# Importing and Deploying .Net Core API to Azure API Managment

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-api-management

I've been trying to create and publish a .Net Core API to Azure. I followed the [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-vsc?view=aspnetcore-2.1) example to create the API. Once the API is created, I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet) example to published it to Azure. I was able to call the API successfully. I am trying to import this API to my API management, but I kept getting the error message

> One or more fields contain incorrect values: Parsing error(s): Error 
>   reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an
>   object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Am I missing something here? Since I've already published the API to azure, why do I need to import and publish it to my API Management?

Here is a screen shot of the error message in azure api management:
[image]

Comment: GET to https://todoapi20180825122240.azurewebsites.net/api/todo seem to return JSON array with some data. You have to provide a URI that produces Open API Specification document: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md. Or register it manually via "Blank API" option, and then creating operations one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are receiving errors importing your OpenAPI document, **ensure you have validated it** - either using the designer in the Azure portal (Design - Front End - OpenAPI Specification Editor), or with a third-party tool such as [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io/).

·**Only JSON format for OpenAPI is supported.**

·Required parameters across both path and query must have unique names. (In OpenAPI a parameter name only needs to be unique within a location, e.g. path, query, header. However, in API Management we allow operations to be discriminated by both path and query parameters (which OpenAPI does not support). Therefore we require parameter names to be unique within the entire URL template.)

·Schemas referenced using $ref properties can't contain other $ref properties.

·**$ref** pointers can't reference external files.

·**x-ms-paths** and **x-servers** are the only supported extensions.

·Custom extensions are ignored on import and are not saved or preserved for export.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-import-restrictions).